# The "model" directive expects a type name

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

After installing .NET Core 3.1 none of Razor's commands work. As you can see in the picture, all Razor commands are red `enter code here`.

```
@model 
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "LessonCreate";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, the `@model` attribute expects a type name of the model. The syntax is:

```
@model TypeNameOfModel
```

You just need to provide the model type to the `@model` attribute, or remove the line, if the Razor view does not use a model.

Razor syntax reference for ASP.NET Core:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-3.1#directive-attributes

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and I had written this

```
@model List<MyModel>()
```

The solution was to simply remove the brackets

```
@model List<MyModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

## for example

### Lesson.cs

```
    namespace MyProject.Models;

    public class Lesson
    {
    ...
    }
```

### Create.cshtml

```
    @model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.Lesson>
```